# Forcing mat-expansion-panel to overflow container element

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-card, mat-expansion-panel

I have a `mat-expansion-panel` inside of a `mat-card`. The expansion panel contains a `mat-chip-list` which contains anywhere between 50-60 `mat-chip` elements.

When I expand this panel, all of my `mat-card` objects are stretched downwards, and the chips show in a column one by one.

What I'm trying to do is have the expansion panel show overtop of its container so the user can see all the mat-chips at once instead of having to scroll down a bunch.

Here's what I'm seeing:
[image]

Here's the code to replicate what I'm seeing:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-8lx7gr

I'm open to alternative ways of achieving this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my approach;

1. in order to prevent `mat-card`s stretching downwards set fixed height on `mat-card-content`

```html
<mat-card-content class="modified-mc-content">
```

in styles.css

```css
.modified-mc-content {
  height: 48px
}
```

As a result `mat-expansion-panel` will overflow mat-card. But it will be behind **Add to Pet!** button. To solve this bring it to front with;

```css
.modified-mc-content > mat-expansion-panel {
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Now `mat-expansion-panel` overflows properly but it causes a scroll on page which is not desirable. Instead I prefer to scroll inside `mat-expansion-panel`. So make `mat-expansion-panel` have a fixed height and scroll;

```css
.modified-mc-content > mat-expansion-panel > .mat-expansion-panel-content {
    max-height: 50vh;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

By setting `height` and `overflow` on `.mat-expansion-panel-content` helps us in two ways;
1. Prevents `mat-expansion-panel` growing beyon page limits.
1. Makes `mat-expansion-panel` content scrollable while header stays put.

To make sure that chips display their content properly, without text overflowing out.

```css
.modified-mc-content mat-chip {
  height: auto
}
```

Finally, make sure that cards properly overlay with each other when `fxLayout.xs="column"` is active.

```html
<mat-card *ngFor="let food of foods;let i = index" [style.z-index]="foods.length - i">
```

Here is a working demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6rsdzw

Hope it helps.